# Desplegar aplicación en Ubuntu con Tomcat 9.0.27 en local

Tags: tomcat, localhost

No soy capaz de desplegar una aplicacion en Ubuntu con Tomcat 9.0.27 para verla en local.
Los pasos que he hecho son los siguientes. Tengo instalados openjdk11 y apache-tomcat. Si pongo a correr Tomcat con `systemctl start tomcat` compruebo que está corriendo usando `systemctl status tomcat` y puedo entrar a la página de tomcat.

He configurado el archivo `/etc/profile`con las siguientes variables de entorno

```
CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/latest/
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/jre/
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME

export PATH JAVA_HOME CATALINA_HOME
```

Creo un proyecto en la carpeta webapps con un index.jsp de prueba y una carpeta WEB-INF que contiene a su vez la carpeta Classes y lib.

**Los problemas**

1) Creo que la variable local CATALINA_HOME no está bien configurada porque no puedo usarla. Tengo que usar rutas absolutas para acceder al directorio de tomcat.

2) No puedo ver en local dicho index entrando en el navegador con la ruta correspondiente a localhost:puerto/webapps, me da error 404

Comment: La variable de $CATALINA_HOME debe apuntar a donde esta tu servidor por lo que veo esta bien si tu servidor esta dentro de la carpeta lastest, existe otra variable predefinida la cual es $CATALINA_BASE la cual apunta a $CATALINA_HOME/webapps gracias a esta variable no es necesario incluir la carpeta webapps en las rutas del servidor, por tal motivo la ruta a la que accedes es incorrecta la ruta correcta seria localhost:puerto/tuapp sin incluir el webapp

Comment: Por otra parte si estas haciendo tu ejemplo a mano recuerda que los proyectos web de java tienen una estructura, por lo que escribes te hace falta el archivo web.xml que es necesario para cualquier aplicacion, te recomiendo mejor crees un proyecto basico en cualquier IDE como Eclipse, lo empaquetes en un WAR y uses el Manajer App de Tomcat para subirlo al servidor